# Event handling: Matplotlib's Figure() and pyplot's figure()

Tags: python, matplotlib

As desribed in http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html the following example code works fine

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

But why does

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.random.rand(10))

def onclick(event):
    print 'button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f'%(
        event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

not work (although it is basically the same)? The error is

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mpl_connect'
```

This really confuses me, as

```
type(fig)
```

gives as expected the same result in both cases:

```
<class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'>
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because when you create a standalone `Figure` instance using `Figure()` , the canvas is not automatically set , you have to set the canvas using the method - [`fig.set_canvas()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_canvas) . Since you did not do this `fig.canvas` is `None` and when you tried to - `fig.canvas.mpl_connect` you got the `AttributeError` .

But when you use `pyplot` and get the figure using - `plt.figure()` - it creates the canvas for you. If you are wondering where , then `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()` internally uses `matplotlib.backend.new_figure_manager()` to create the figure, and that (depending on the backend) creates the figure , Example for `gtk` it is available [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py) - line 99 -

```
canvas = FigureCanvasGTK(figure)
```